# Cannot resize notes field on form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise.

I am editing the Case/Incident form. I want to make the notes field smaller than it is by default.

However, I cannot seem to shorten the height of the field with the mouse (although I can move it with difficulty)

I can edit the properties of the field and of its parent section and it is shown as being the size I want in the form editor:
[image]

I saved and published the changes. (Several times!)

However, the notes field is much larger when the form is used:
[image]

Here's the Formatting page of the Notes Properties dialogue:
[image]

Here's the Formatting page of the Section Properties dialogue:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The notes control is always a 2-column control and you can't change that. If you want to change it's size, you'll need to add a 3 or 4 column section and move it into that. It will then fill up 2 columns - either then left, middle or right.

Comment: Sorry - should have been more specific. I want it to be shorter (in height). The width is fine.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to remove the standard notes section and re-insert the notes control - this then allows you to change the height.

Comment: I can't do that - the Remove button is disabled. See my question. I created another question since I didn't understand the problem enough when creating this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156641/cannot-edit-or-remove-notes-field

Comment: Ok, I have removed the Notes field and added another. Now I can edit the properties. But it still doesn't work! I've updated the question.

Comment: I'm guessing that the notes field has a fixed height then :/

Comment: Just done a quick test and the formxml is: <cell id="{91539bc1-5a07-4c87-b38e-44110e81c863}" showlabel="true" rowspan="1" auto="false" colspan="2" locklevel="0">
                    <control id="notescontrol" classid="{06375649-c143-495e-a496-c962e5b4488e}" disabled="false" />
                  </cell>

But the notes control is still the full height - so it must be something built into the notes control that sets the height

Answer (score 0):

From Suresh Sorde at http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8fb21a62-14e0-435a-bffd-4fa18c27e989/how-to-resize-notes-field-on-form

I dont think there is a way to change note size.