# Cannot edit or remove notes field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise.

I cannot resize the notes field with the mouse (although I can move it around the form with difficulty) and the Change Properties and Remove ribbon buttons are disabled when I select the notes field and double clicking the notes field does nothing.

[image]

What could be the cause? How can I find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the parent *section* (not the notes control it's self) and then add a new Notes control (Insert=> Notes) - this will then allow you to resize.